# Add a header line to text output from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, printing

I would like to add a line of `----` to the output I am writing from `PowerShell`.
There are multiple lines being added to the text file similar to the code I have pasted here and I would like to just have this `----` added as a line before the output to quickly differentiate the info when looking at it.

```
"New Starter- " +$FirstName + " " +  $Lastname + ", " + "User Name- " + $SAMAccountLower + ", " + "Temp Password- " +$TmpPass | Set-Content "c:\temp\${SAMAccountLower}_login.txt"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to overwrite the contents of an existing file, you can use `Add-Content`. If you want to overwrite a file or start a new file, then change `Add-Content` to `Set-Content`. I tend to favor using the format operator (`-f`) for string formatting/building, which can protect from certain issues with `+` concatenation.

```
'----' | Add-Content "c:\temp\${SAMAccountLower}_login.txt"
"New Starter- {0} {1}, User Name- {2}, Temp Password- {3}" -f $FirstName,$LastName,$SamAccountLower,$TmpPass |
    Add-Content "c:\temp\${SAMAccountLower}_login.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks, yeh the set-content has made a difference to the overwriting aspect of this also.  Cheers for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
"----- " + "New Starter- " +$FirstName + " " +  $Lastname + ", " + "User Name- " + $SAMAccountLower + ", " + "Temp Password- " +$TmpPass | Set-Content "c:\temp\${SAMAccountLower}_login.txt"
```

You mean like this^ or like this?

```
"-----`n" + "New Starter- " +$FirstName + " " +  $Lastname + ", " + "User Name- " + $SAMAccountLower + ", " + "Temp Password- " +$TmpPass | Set-Content "c:\temp\${SAMAccountLower}_login.txt"
```

Comment: I wanted to have a line of ---- then the output, but I just read up about using "@  

`$UserInfo = @"
---
New Starter Name: $FirstName $Lastname
Username: $SAMAccountLower
Temp Password: $tmpPass
---
"@

'$UserInfo | Set-Content "c:\temp\${SAMAccountLower}_login.txt"`

Comment: sorry that reply is really messy.

Comment: I am assuming you are getting the data from `Get-ADUser` command. Simply displaying the return object itself would look better. Since they are objects, you can add the `Temp Password` as a property using `add-member` cmdlet if you wish. But whatever works for you. There will always be multiple ways of handling it. personally, I would always like to handle it as a object. That way, it will always be a unit.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood, you want to write your line proceeded by --- like this:

```
< something written here >
-------------------------- 
< Your line here >
```

Try this:

```
$text = "New Starter- " +$FirstName + " " +  $Lastname + ", " + "User Name- " + $SAMAccountLower + ", " + "Temp Password- " +$TmpPass;
$seperator = '-'*$text.Length + "`n";
$seperator + $text | Set-Content "c:\temp\${SAMAccountLower}_login.txt";
```

**NOTE**

I think `Set_Content` removes the previous content of the file and write the new text, i don't know if this is your case.